# Background image on iphone is not diplaying properly

Tags: iphone, css, background

I have a background image that displays as it should on the computer but for some reason it's become too small (like half the size it should be when viewing it on my iphone. Something has caused this to happen as I've been working on the page because this wasn't the case earlier today.

this is the css for the div containing the bg img. Any ideas on whats going on?

```
#wrapper{
    position:relative;
    width:1000px;
    height:5854px;
    background-image:url(../images/UnearthingBG.jpg);
    background-color:#000;
    margin-top: 75px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
```

This is the working page http://www.unearthingfilm.com/Test.html

Comment: Funny, if I cut the image to a height of `2000px` it works.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix it last night using `background-size: cover.`

Thank you for your answers. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I've just tested your site out on my iPhone and the background image looks to appear fine. I've added a screenshot blow. It's possible that your iPhone has had an error and is cache a file somewhere.

I suggest possible try going to *** Settings -> Safari -> Clear Cookies and Data ***

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work on my iPhone 3GS with setting the `background-size`:

```
#wrapper {
    -webkit-background-size: 1000px 5854px;
}
```

This is hacky, but did the job here. I should tell, my iPhone is just for playing sudoku and didn't get any update for years, so it runs iOS 3. ;)

Here may be the reason: http://medialab.zendesk.com/entries/22472177-Large-image-as-browser-background-not-working-on-iPhone-Safari-browser

> Your problem is caused by mobile safari. It simply shrinks down all images that are larger than 2Mpx.

Don't know if it's true, but it makes sense.